# Jakarta Faces 10 Programmatic Views

Tags: jakarta-ee

What is the correct way of adding a link to the head element of an Html document using Jakarta Faces 10 programmatic views?

I have tried creating a UIOutput, but I cannot reference the CSS file in the project resources directory.

Answer (score 0):

Create a /resources directory in the root of your site, create libraries directories inside it, see the screenshot from NetBeans below.

[image: Jakarta JSF project in NetBeans]

After that, you can add the appropriate files to the libraries, for example, to the /resources/styles library, let's add the main.css styles file.

Now add link from to this file from your JSF page.

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="styles" name="main.css"/>
```

The question is not very informative, I hope I understood it correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using Jakara 10 Faces 4.0. Faces now support programmatically created pages, whereas before you could only use markup to create pages. My question pertains to the new programmatic views. The <h:outputStylesheet is no longer needed.